# StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper

Tenho um projeto em JSF, utilizo o NetBeans.
Essa função gera um relatório jasper e estava funcionando normal, mas depois de compilar o projeto passou a lançar a exceção `util.loader.object.from.input.stream.loading.error`

O problema é nessa linha: `JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(stream);`

O problema não é a localização do .jasper nem do subrelatório, já que vi debugando que o stream é carregado.

o código da função:

```
public void reciboMensal(CobMensal cob, Date data, String user) throws FileNotFoundException {

    stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ReciboGrp.jasper");
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try{
        params.put("idben", cob.getBen().getId());
        params.put("data", data);
        params.put("usuario", user); 

        JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(stream);
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, getConexao());
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, baos);

        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(baos.size());
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=recibo.pdf");
        response.getOutputStream().write(baos.toByteArray());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close();

        context.responseComplete();
        fecharConexao();      

    }catch (JRException | IOException ex)  {
        Logger.getLogger(Relatorio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Caused da stack

```
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:866)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.<init>(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:56)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:277)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:262)
    at br.soames.report.Relatorio.reciboMensal(Relatorio.java:62)
```

Podem ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema era com o Maven e seus filtros. Aparentemente, ao compilar, ele codificava os arquivos .jasper e acabava corrompendo-os.
A solução foi sinalizar a extensão .jasper para não ser filtrada pelo Maven, colocando no pom.xml:

```
                 <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                      <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                      <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jrxml</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jasper</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                      </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    </configuration>
                  </plugin>
```

E depois copiar novamente os arquivos.

Answer (score 0):

Como eu uso Spring boot, não informei a versão e ficou assim:

```
     <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                     <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                              <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                                
<nonFilteredFileExtension>jrxml</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                                <nonFilteredFileExtension>jasper</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                              </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                            </configuration>
                          </plugin>
                </plugins>
```